# not recieved the data in laravel datatable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to fetch data using datatable in laravel. My

`view` is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var oTable;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        oTable = $('#data').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "order": [],
            "columns":[
                    {"data":"start_date"},
                    {"data":"end_date"},
                    {"data":"client_id"},
                    {"data":"created_at"},
                    {"data":"actions"}
            ],
            "ajax": "{{ url('contract') }}" + ((typeof $('#data').attr('data-id') != "undefined") ? "/" + $('#id').val() + "/" + $('#data').attr('data-id') : "/data")
        });
    });

    function deleteClient(id){

    }
</script>


 public function data(Datatables $datatables)
{

    $contObj = new Contract;
    $conttt = $contObj->get()
        ->map(function ($conttt) {
        return [
            'id' => $conttt->id,
            'start_date' => $conttt->start_date,
            'end_date' => $conttt->end_date,
          'client_id' => $conttt->user_id,
            'created_at' => $conttt->created_at
        ];
    });

    return $datatables->collection($conttt)

        ->addColumn('actions', '@if(Sentinel::inRole(\'admin\'))
                                <a href="{{ url(\'contract/\' . $id . \'/edit\' ) }}" title="{{ trans(\'table.edit\') }}">
                                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil text-warning "></i> </a>
                                @endif
                                <a href="{{ url(\'contract/\' . $id . \'/show\' ) }}" title="{{ trans(\'table.details\') }}" >
                                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-eye text-primary"></i> </a>
                               ')

        ->removeColumn('id')
        ->rawColumns(['actions'])->make();
}
```

but when I am getting this data as :

```
"data":[{"start_date":null,"end_date":null,"client_id":"3","created_at":{"date":"2018-08-07 10:13:46.000000","timezone_type":"3","timezone":"UTC"},"actions":"                                    <a href=\"http:\/\/billing.mj.milesweb.cloud\/files\/public\/contract\/1\/edit\" title=\"Edit\">\n                                            <i class=\"fa fa-fw fa-pencil text-warning \"><\/i> <\/a>\n                                                                        <a href=\"http:\/\/billing.mj.milesweb.cloud\/files\/public\/contract\/1\/show\" title=\"Show\" >\n                                            <i class=\"fa fa-fw fa-eye text-primary\"><\/i> <\/a>\n                                   "}
```

When I see this data in datatable then I see in field `created_at` the data shown there is `[object Object]` while in json it is OK. Please help me to show the proper data in datatable

Answer (score 0):

It's because `created_at` is a Carbon object and you need a string. For 'created_at', try returning the following:

```
\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $conttt->created_at)->format('m/d/y h:i A')
```

Answer (score 0):

By default created_at and updated_at are the carbon class object. You need to convert it into your own format:

```
$conttt = $contObj->get()
    ->map(function ($conttt) {
    return [
        'id' => $conttt->id,
        'start_date' => $conttt->start_date,
        'end_date' => $conttt->end_date,
      'client_id' => $conttt->user_id,
        'created_at' => $conttt->created_at->format('d-m-Y')
    ];
});
```

You also can write this code into Your model class. For that  you need to user Laravel [mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators).
Good Luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

you can editColoumn in datatable like this:

```
return Datatables::of($conttt)
            ->editColumn('created_at', function($conttt) {
                return $conttt->created_at->format('d M Y H:i:s');
            })
            ->make(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

try it

1)

```
$contObj = new Contract;
$conttt = $contObj->get()
    ->map(function ($conttt) {
    return [
        'id' => $conttt->id,
        'start_date' => $conttt->start_date,
        'end_date' => $conttt->end_date,
      'client_id' => $conttt->user_id,
        'created_at' => date('Y-m-d h:s:i', strtotime($conttt->created_at))
    ];
});
```

2)

```
$contObj = Contract::all();
```